# GNOME shell extension "Applications Menu" not working

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I have 2 same notebooks running on Ubuntu 18.04.

[Applications Menu by fmuellner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/) is installed on both, but it doesn't show any menu item on one of them.

There are 2 differences between them:

1. the working one runs on higher kernel the other one uses the default kernel
2. the working one uses English language the other uses another one

Any idea how can I find out what the problem is?

There is no error message or any useful information in

```
journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell
```

Comment: Both installed locally (or system-wide)?

Comment: good point! Does it affect the working any how?
On the working one it is installed system-wide and on the other one it is locally installed. On my debian system the locally installed version works.

Comment: It shouldn't, but looks like it does! Also same version?

Comment: same version on the Ubuntu systems

Answer (score 4):

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Type `lg`
3. Click 'Extensions'
4. 'Show errors' below Application Menu
5. If error is `this._button.hotCorner is undefined` just enable it
   (Gnome Tweak Tool: Top Bar → Activities Overview Hot Corner)
   Or edit the extension.js :)
   [github gnome-shell-extensions](https://github.com/AndreasBottcher/gnome-shell-extensions/commit/8fbcb11b070b7632633529d89827a09864d53a5b)